# Complex join in Laravel query builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, query-builder

I have a complex join query that I'm not able to create with Laravel query builder,

the RAW expression is the following:

```
select r.counted,day (date) as day, month   (date) as month, year   (date) from dates 

left join (select created_at,COUNT(created_at) counted ,day (created_at) as day, month  (created_at) as month, year (created_at) as year from analytics 
where type = 1
and project_id = 1
group by `year`, `month`, `day`
order by `year` desc) r

on `dates`.`date` = DATE_FORMAT(r.created_at, '%Y-%m-%d') 
where `date` between '2015-01-01' and '2015-02-01'
```

Basically what I want it to have all analytics count by day, and get the dates that doesn't have value too

I have the model `date` and the model `analytic` 
`analytic` already has its scopes `scopeProject` and `scopeType` that filters the initial data

Thank you!

Comment: have you tried running DB::statement( ) or similar raw commands?

Comment: Yes, with a DB::select(DB::raw()) works, but I would like to have a query so I can chain the scopes